# Unix: Getting execl functions to read from stdin

Tags: c, unix, stdin, pipe

I'm having trouble calling execl with "/usr/bin/sort" in a C program I'm writing. The call to sort doesn't seem to be reading from stdin or printing any output. Code below:

```
// forking children, creating pipes, etc.
// ...
// These lines:

char msg[256];
read(pipe2[0], msg, 256*10);
printf("%s\n", msg);

//Produce this output:

bash-4.2/make_cmd.c:2
bash-4.2/mailcheck.h:0
bash-4.2/findcmd.c:6
bash-4.2/command.h:4
bash-4.2/config-top.h:1
bash-4.2/redir.c:2
bash-4.2/variables.c:7
bash-4.2/unwind_prot.c:0
bash-4.2/arrayfunc.h:0
bash-4.2/variables.h:0
bash-4.2/bracecomp.c:0
...

// So I know that pipe2[1] is being written to by the previous child.
// but for some reason this child will not read from pipe2[0]

   pid_3 = fork();
   if (pid_3 == 0) {
     /* Third Child */
     memset(cmdbuf, 0, BSIZE);
     dup2(pipe2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
     dup2(pipe3[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
     close(pipe2[0]);
     close(pipe3[1]);
     sprintf(cmdbuf, "/usr/bin/sort -t : +1.0 -2.0 --numeric --reverse");
     if(execl("/usr/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", cmdbuf, (char*)NULL) < 0){
        perror("Error calling sort: ");
        return(-1);
     }
     exit(0);
   } 


// and after "reading..." is printed, the program hangs instead of
// printing "parent: [whatever the output of sort would be]\n"

printf("reading...\n");
read(pipe3[0], msg, BSIZE);
printf("parent: %s\n", msg);
exit(0);
```

Even if I pass cmdbuf as "-t :" or pass the call to sort without arguments nothing happens. I've also tried passing sort directly without /usr/bin/bash like so

```
execl("/usr/bin/sort", "sort", (char*)NULL);
```

to no avail.

Comment: `exec.*` functions return a value. Ignore it to your own peril. See also: errno, perror.

Comment: I've added an if statement in my actual code to check if exec worked, and also added perror, thanks for the tip. however the code still hangs after the call to read(pipe3[0], msg, BSIZE); with no ouptut or error message from the exec call. I'll update the code here to the current source

Comment: `read` returns a value too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not so obvious if you're someone who's new to using pipes in UNIX.

My program opened 3 total pipes. Each child was using only two of these pipes apiece to route their stdin and stdout data. For each child, I was only closing the pipes that were dup2'ed over to the stdin and stdout file descriptors for that child. Apparently this is a no-no, and the correct way to do things is to have every child close every pipe whenever they are done calling dup2. source: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html